# Integer to base 16 conversion

Tags: java, radix

So far I have a method that can convert to different bases to 2, 8, but I can't seem to figure out how to do 16. The thing about 16 is when it hits 9, it should print out letters like:

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F

but I'm struggling to understand how to get this answer if I'm dealing with ints. We are not allowed to use any arrays.

```
public static void conversion(int integer, int base) {
    if (integer > 0 && base > 0) {
        System.out.println(integer + " in binary -> "+ Integer.toString(integer, base));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that code something you've attempted? What does it do?

Comment: Basically the user puts in an integer and a base like 100 and 2. Then it will output the binary correctly. The problem with 16 is that if I put in any number it should have one or more ABCDEF replacing the last digits of the number. I'm having trouble figuring it out but here is a link that explain the conversion if it helps: http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/~ram/cpsc110/inclass/conversions.html

Comment: No I understand hex, what I don't understand is what your problem is. It looks like you've already got working code, which is essentially just a wrapper for Integer's toString method, which already works perfectly. Have you put in 16 for the radix?

Comment: ex: `System.out.println(Integer.toString(255, 16));` prints `ff`

Comment: The problem is the code is not outputting the numbers with letters. What do you mean by radix?

Comment: Ok, edit your post with what inputs you've tried and what outputs you expect..

Comment: This is what I've tried so far.

Comment: String hex = "ABCDEF";
int integer = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
System.out.println(integer + " in binary -> " + Integer.toString(integer, base));

Comment: I mean edit your post not include another comment..radix is another word for "base". If all you want to convert an integer in base 10 to base 16, you have working code, as evident by my comments: 255 (in base 10) = ff (in base 16)

Comment: I got it, you are right. Also a quick question, is it possible to set the digits ff to upper case?

Comment: I tried doing that but I got this error: "void cannot be dereferenced"

Comment: Parenthesis in the wrong place..: System.out.println(Integer.toString(255, 16).toUpperCase());

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your patience with me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using println, consider using format. This will allow you to keep the value but display it in any manner that you're able to format it.

For instance:

```
System.out.format("The number as Base 16 is %x", x);
```

I hope this answers your question. Comment below if not!

Comment: This will simply print out the number. If value is 9, then "9" will be printed. Op wants to print value with specific base.

Comment: @Kao `9` in decimal is `9` in hex anyways :P

Answer (score 0):

The above method seems correct. Though you can also use

```
Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(n), 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method works fine.

You can change the output string to uppercase if that is your main issue:

```
public static void conversion(int integer, int base) 
    {
    if (integer > 0 && base > 0) {
        System.out.println(integer + " in binary -> "+ (Integer.toString(integer, base)).toUpperCase());
    }
}
```